# Difference between "I'm in the school" and "I'm in school"

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, sentence-meaning

What is the difference between these two sentences??

> I'm in the school.
>   I'm in school.

Do they have the same meaning or not?

Comment: Note that, in British English, you'd be more likely to say "I'm at school" than "I'm in school".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I'm in the school.

Means I am in the building (but I may not be a student).

> I'm in school.

Means I am attending school (I'm a student).

Comment: This is true, but curiously I find I'm inclined to assign precisely the *opposite* connotations to *"I'm in [the] **church**"*.

Comment: This is not necessarily true. "I'm in the school" is a perfectly normal way to say that you attend the school being referred to. (For example, if X tells Y, "you should ask someone in the school", Z can easily interpose, "I'm in the school" (meaning "ask me!"), whether or not (s)he is literally in the school building at the time.)

Comment: Also on that note, I've often seen "I'm in school" to literally mean "I'm inside the school building". In this case it's the answer to "Where are you?" when the asker is aware of what school you're talking about

Answer (score 2):

**The** is used to refer to someone or something that has already been mentioned, or a context that has previously been established or easily understood.

---

> I'm in **the** school

This sentence is generally understood to refer to a **physical location at a particular school**. "In the school" means you are inside the building, "at the school" means you are on school grounds.

"The school" makes sense if the school's identity is clearly known or obvious.

"The school" difficult to understand (or plain nonsense) if the school's identity is unknown or unclear.

---

> I'm in school

This sentence is not specific to any school, therefore **the** is not used.

In this sense, "school" is understood to  mean **schooling**, or the process of receiving an education, rather than a physical school.

To be "in school" is to be **in attendance** at a non-specific school.

One would specify a school this way:

> I'm in school at ___________

Which is an informal way of saying:

> I *attend* school at ___________

Comment: I agree with most of this, but not the reason for omitting "the". The word _the_ is omitted because we don't use it when we are talking about attending school. _"Teddy, next Monday is Columbus Day; are you in school on Monday?"_ Even if everyone in the room is aware that Teddy goes to Springfield Middle School, we still leave out the "the".

Answer (score 2):

We do not use the definite article "the" with the words **church, bed, college, court, hospital, prison, school, university** *when we refer to the purpose for which they exist*. e.g. “**Sally went to school**" (She's a student.)
But:**"Her father went to the school to see her teacher yesterday."** (He went to the school as a visitor.)

Comment: Americans generally say _to the hospital_. Canadians and Brits just say _to hospital_.

Comment: Vic, is this a comprehensive list? I wonder why I does not apply to "cinema and gym".

Answer (score 1):

I am in the school and I am in school are different in meaning.

When I talk about being in school, it means I am a student there.

When I talk about being in the school (school building), it means I am not a student there. Maybe I am in the school to look around the school building or to see my father who is a teacher there.

Comment: "I'm in the school" does not say that you're not a student there, it's moot on that.  It's simply addressing your physical location.