# Why "cut in line" doesn't have an article?

Tags: articles

There is a expression "cut in line" and it seems there is no expression "cut in the line".

According to a dictionary the word "line" is not uncountable. Why the phrase doesn't have the article?

Comment: You can also say cut in a line and cut in the line, but cut in line is far more common.

Comment: "cut in line" is an expression rather than a sentence fragment.  That's how it is commonly used.  Just "cut in" is also common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [ngram comparison with *to skip*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+skip+in+line%2Cto+skip+line%2C+to+skip+the+line&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20skip%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20skip%20the%20line%3B%2Cc0) instead of *to cut*, because the context for *to cut* might be other types of lines, e.g. the wire.

***to skip line*** and ***to skip the line*** are equally prominent, whereas *in* and *in the* don't seem to be used in this context in books. So *to cut the line* couldn't be wrong, by analogy.

Compare this question with [*go home*](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56381/whats-the-difference-between-go-go-to-and-go-to-the?s=2|0.5282)' (which is a [recurring question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/56406/question-about-diffrenece-between-go-to-home-go-home?s=1|2.4276)).

Between *cut* and *skip* there might be a difference, because 'to have cut line' doesn't quite roll of the tongue as well, although, *cutting line* with or without additional particles would, so I suppose it might stem from a confusion of *to be cutt**in'** *' (the) line* and *to cut into* (or the [generally less](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+cut+in%2Cto+cut+into&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20cut%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20cut%20into%3B%2Cc0) prominent *to cut in*).

Ultimately, I don't think there is a correct answer, as far as grammar is concerned. According to google ngram this type of expression gained prominence only [after the 1970s](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=to+cut+in+line%2Cto+skip+line&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20cut%20in%20line%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cto%20skip%20line%3B%2Cc0).