# What does make “home”, “school” and “work” exceptional gramatically?

Tags: grammar

"work", "home" and "school" can be uncountable and be used without an article. What does make them so special? Are there other words like them?

In other words, why do I have to say "I'm going to **the** gym/uni"? But I don't need "the" for home/work/school.

Comment: Don't forget "church", "bed", meals (often), and "soccer practice" :)

Comment: It has often been pointed out on this site that _go to school, church_ and, in British English, _hospital_ mean _attend classes, attend a service_ and _be a patient_, while you can go to _the_ school, church or hospital as a visitor, to meet someone etc.

Comment: You don't need "the" for "uni". "University/uni" is in that list of special words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The three words "work", "home" and "school" are all special because they can be used without articles where grammar normally requires one. They're actually part of *three different sets of words*.

Membership in all the sets is arbitrary. That's to say, there's no rule to know whether a word is in that category or not. So it's just a historical accident that "home", "school" and "work" are in these three sets, but "house", "madrassa", and "office" are outside the sets, even though they have roughly the same meanings.

**Set 1**

Words like "school" are in one set of place nouns that allows them to be used without articles in certain places where other place nouns require articles. Without the article, the phrase indicates that *the purpose for being at the place is to participate in the normal function of that place*.

> Victor went **to a church** (*He went to a church building; no information about why*)
> Victor went **to church**. (*He went to attend church service*)
> My sister is **in the jail**. (*She's inside the jail building; no information about why*)
> My sister is **in jail**. (*She's a prisoner*)

I searched for a complete list but didn't find one. This is the most complete list I was able to compile.

- jail
- school
- church
- bed
- court
- college
- university
- prison
- hospital

"Hospital" is slightly different in that "Luke is **in the hospital**" is ambiguous, and can mean either that Luke is a patient, or simply inside the building. Context is required to make clear which is the case.

**Set 2**

There's a second set of nouns like "work" and names of activities. These are different from the first set in that *they are not place names, and using an article before them is meaningless*:

> Shelly just came from work. (*She was doing her job there*)
> <del>Shelly just came from the work.</del> (*bad grammar or different meaning*)
> Andrew's at poker. (*He's playing in a poker game*)
> <del>Andrew's at the poker.</del> (*bad grammar*)

**Set 3**

There are also some other place words like "home" and "downtown" that *are considered adverbs or function as adverbs* when used without an article. They don't have the same meaning of *going somewhere for the intended purpose of that place*, and it's either ungrammatical to use them with an article, or the meaning changes.

> I'm going home. (*adverb; simply indicates travel; no special meaning about the purpose of "home"*)
> I'm going to a home. (*noun; probably means a nursing home, old age home, home for foster children, etc.*)
> Harold lives downtown. (*indicates a location*)
> <del>Harold lives in the downtown.</del> (*bad grammar*)

Comment: Congress can be added to set 1?

Comment: @HandsomeNerd We never refer to "Congress" as "The Congress" or "A Congress", so no. There's also no specific activity associated with "go to Congress". It just means moving from one place to another, same as "go to the bank".

Comment: congress and not Congress I meant.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd Then I don't understand. How is "congress" a place? Set 1 is all physical locations, and other than "bed", they're all buildings. I've never heard of a place called "congress" other than when referring to the US Capitol building.

Comment: it's an abstract location or place. It's like other gathering nouns. When you say I'm going to a meeting it's like a place that you go, a place that others are. Other words include group, team, forum, and council ... 

Also, I don't care if it's a physical place or not. I mean the first group grammatically.

Comment: Also note that "in *the* hospital" is particular to US English. British English speakers don't say that; we say "in hospital". So no ambiguity for us.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that there is a hard and fast rule.

It may be that the article is more likely to be omitted if you are actively engaged in what is happening at the location.

A clue to this is sports. If you say:

"I'm going to cricket", that would usually imply that you were taking part in a match or practice.

On the other hand, if you say "I am going to the cricket", it generally means that you are going to watch a match.

That's not infallible, though, because we don't say "I'm going to café", even though we do actively engage in something (eating and drinking), there.

Comment: Thanks, so are it correct to say "I'm going to gym/uni." too? Because similarly, we engaged in what happens there.

Comment: But there *are* hard-and-fast rules about this. Please only give answers you're confident about rather than guessing based on your intuition. Giving half correct answers doesn't do the OPs any good

Comment: @gotube so what are the hard-and-fast rules you mentioned?

Comment: @HandsomeNerd, saying "*I am going to university.*" is saying what your current education level is, whereas "*I am going to the university*" is saying where you will physically be in the immediate future.

Comment: @HandsomeNerd Check out [Vic's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/37563/113306) at this other question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140250/discussion-on-answer-by-prl75-what-does-make-home-school-and-work-excepti).

Comment: @RayButterworth thanks, so why cannot I say "I go to gym/cinema."

Comment: @HandsomeNerd, one could say "I go to gym three times a week.", without implying that it is the same physical location. It could be Gold's Gym on Mondays, Goodlife Fitness on Wednesdays, and LA Fitness on Fridays.  Using "*the* gym" implies a specific location, which the listener knows. ¶ As for "cinema", I don't know why, but it would sound wrong to say "I go to cinema". In fact many people would say "I go to *the* cinema every week" even when it is a different location each time. Same thing for "theatre".

Comment: @RayButterworth thanks for your comment. My grammar checking tool thinks "I go to gym three times a week. " is not correct and suggests adding "the".

Comment: @HandsomeNerd I would definitely say "I go to *the* gym 3 times a week" even if it is different gyms each time. "go to the gym" just means "work out at a gym." Similarly, without more context, the *assumed* meaning is that you're exercising there, not just being in the building.