# Which locations do not get prepositions?

Tags: prepositions

I realised words like "home" and "uptown/downtown" are different like
you say "I go downtown." instead of "I go to downtown.". Can you explain and provide other similar words?

Interestingly midtown still needs "to".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does make “home”, “school” and “work” exceptional gramatically?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/326221/what-does-make-home-school-and-work-exceptional-gramatically)

Comment: @Astralbee thanks, it does not. If it does please explain here.

Comment: This can be confusing because uptown and downtown can mean not only destinations (I will be uptown tomorrow), but also directions (I am headed downtown after work).

Comment: I got some good info from a related question here. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33652/why-is-to-not-used-before-home

It's unfortunate that two people have marked the question as unclear when it's simple and straightforward like the linked question.